# CloudFormation TemplateURL Cross Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

we have a management account for our different environments where we store data in a central location. I have a json file to be used as a stack in one of our AWS accounts. The templateURL property in aws::cloudformation::stack must point to the S3 bucket in the management account. I created a role in the dev account that trusts the main account and allows access to s3. I have tested access by using the "Switch Role" feature in AWS. I have attached that role to CloudFormation during the "Create Stack" step. However, when it is launched specifying the URL of the S3 bucket in the main account, I get error "templateURL must reference a valid S3 object to which you have access."

Looking for advice or help and much appreciated :)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem. My cross-account bucket permissions seem to be correct and can be verified, but this specific TemplateURL parameter fails.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this was because I uploaded the file with the assumed role. Try uploading the file with the management account then running your stack. Something about how the bucket owner flag works, I can check my notes tomorrow for you if that doesn't work.